# ParserError: Expected ':' but got 'payable'

Tags: solidity, truffle, erc-721, openzeppelin

```
function buyStar(uint256 _tokenId) public payable {
        require(starsForSale[_tokenId] > 0, "The star must be available for sale!"); // the star to buy must be in starsForSale mapping
        uint256 starPrice = starsForSale[_tokenId]; // get the price of the star for sale
        address starOwner = ownerOf(_tokenId); // get the owner of the star
        require(msg.value >= starPrice, "You need to have sufficient funds!"); // check the bidding price is greater than or equal to the stars for sale price
        _transfer(starOwner, msg.sender, _tokenId);
        address payable starOwnerAddressPayable = payable(starOwner);
        starOwnerAddressPayable.transfer(starPrice);
        if(msg.value > starPrice) {
            msg.sender.transfer(msg.value - starPrice);
        }
    }
```

The error which is showing up is
 `ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'payable' address payable starOwnerAddressPayable = starOwner;`

Compilation failed. See above.

what is the latest way to overcome this.

Comment: Hi there. What version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: Hi. I am using ^0.8.4. Solved. `function _make_payable(address x) internal pure returns(address payable) { return payable(address(uint160(x)); } `added this ^ function and made `starOwnerAddressPayable = _make_payable(starOwner)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the error was in line

```
address payable starOwnerAddressPayable = payable(starOwner);
```

Which was rectified by using _make_payable function. It was solved.

Final Code review-

```
function _make_payable(address x) internal pure returns (address payable) {
        return payable(address(uint160(x)));
    }

    function buyStar(uint256 _tokenId) public payable {
        require(starsForSale[_tokenId] > 0, "The star must be available for sale!"); // the star to buy must be in starsForSale mapping
        uint256 starPrice = starsForSale[_tokenId]; // get the price of the star for sale
        address starOwner = ownerOf(_tokenId); // get the owner of the star
        require(msg.value >= starPrice, "You need to have sufficient funds!"); // check the bidding price is greater than or equal to the stars for sale price
        _transfer(starOwner, msg.sender, _tokenId);
        address payable starOwnerAddressPayable = _make_payable(starOwner);
        address payable newOwnerAddressPayable = _make_payable(msg.sender);
        starOwnerAddressPayable.transfer(starPrice);
        if(msg.value > starPrice) {
            newOwnerAddressPayable.transfer(msg.value - starPrice);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your actual code is so I made function for reference it works fine for me.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract test {
    uint256[] starsForSale;
    
    function ownerOf(uint256 some) public returns(address){
        return msg.sender;
    }
    
    function _transfer(address from, address _to, uint256 amount) public {
        
    }
    

    function buyStar(uint256 _tokenId) public payable {
        require(starsForSale[_tokenId] > 0, "The star must be available for sale!"); // the star to buy must be in starsForSale mapping
        uint256 starPrice = starsForSale[_tokenId]; // get the price of the star for sale
        address starOwner = ownerOf(_tokenId); // get the owner of the star
        require(msg.value >= starPrice, "You need to have sufficient funds!"); // check the bidding price is greater than or equal to the stars for sale price
        _transfer(starOwner, msg.sender, _tokenId);
        address payable starOwnerAddressPayable = payable(starOwner);
        starOwnerAddressPayable.transfer(starPrice);
        if(msg.value > starPrice) {
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(msg.value - starPrice);
        }
    }
}
```

I think you got error in `address payable starOwnerAddressPayable = starOwner;`.

But in your code you wrote like `address payable starOwnerAddressPayable = payable(starOwner);` so I think you forgot to save?

Comment: Actually the _transfer and ownerOf are ERC721 methods. in the ERC721.sol . yes the error was in line `address payable starOwnerAddressPayable = payable(starOwner);`. Which was rectified by using _make_payable function. `function _make_payable(address x) internal pure returns(address payable) { return payable(address(uint160(x)); } `. it was solved.